# Problems with text-align: center property in the table

Tags: html, css

I made this one :

https://jsfiddle.net/6wb2xedc/

```css
.price-table {
  display: table;
  width: 630px;
  height: 233px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 51px;
}

.price-table ul {
  display: table-row;
}

.price-table__content {
  display: table-row-group;
  border: 1px #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-table__content ul {
  display: table-row;
}

.price-table__content ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 5px;
}

.price-table__content ul li:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  padding-left: 138px;
}

.price-table__content ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  text-align: left;
}

.price-table__content ul li:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 153px;
}

.price-table__content ul li:nth-child(4) {
  padding-left: 140px;
}

.price-table__content ul li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 142px;
  padding-top: 42px;
}

.price-table__content-third-row {
  display: table-footer-group;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-table__headers {
  display: table-header-group;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price-table__headers ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 13px;
}

.price-table__headers ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 107px;
  border: none;
}

.price-table__headers ul li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 65px;
}

.price-table__headers ul li:last-child {
  padding-left: 71px;
}

.price-table__headers ul li:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 55px;
}

.price-table__headers ul li:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  background-color: #283645;
}

.price-table__headers ul li span {
  text-align: center;
}

.price-table__headers__column {
  display: table-column;
}

.price-table__headers__column-group {
  display: table-column-group;
}
```

```html
<section class="price-block">
  <article class="price-table">
    <div class="price-table__column-group">
      <div class="price-table__column"></div>
      <div class="price-table__column"></div>
      <div class="price-table__column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price-table__column-last">
      <div class="price-table__headers-content">
        <header class="price-table__headers">
          <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li>
              <div><span>База</span> <span class="price-table__item-value"><br>1,99 USD</span></div>
            </li>
            <li><span>Стандарт</span> <span class="price-table__item-value"><br>3,99 USD</span></li>
            <li><span>Анлим</span> <span class="price-table__item-value"><br>9,99 USD</span></li>
          </ul>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="price-table__content">
        <ul class="price-table__content-fist-row">
          <li>Розовый фильтр</li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="price-table__content-second-row">
          <li>Смайлики</li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="price-table__content-third-row">
          <li>Комментарии</li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

The problem is that i can't center text in spans (class "price-table__headers") using

```
  text-align:center;
```

or move it using margin:left or right inside of the block without stretching table-cells.

Comment: Did you get a warning that you shouldn't like link to JS Fiddle but should provide the code in the question itself? Did you ignore that in favour of just writing a single line of code in the question to make the warning go away? Don't do that. Provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Note the keyword "minimal"  in Quentin's link. Just copy/pasting everything isn't 'minimal'. You may want to read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Because of your padding, your inner cells are kind of off. Therefore `text-align: center` won't center your text according to the full cell width but the space that is left.

Comment: Your `span` elements are displayed inline, meaning they are only as wide as the content requires. Therefor trying to “center” that content makes no sense of course, because the remaining space you have left to divide up evenly on both sides is _zero_ to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, I will be more attentive next time and thanks for all your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was quite a few bits wrong with that. There's some unnecessary nesting, and padding-left on `.price-table__headers ul li`

[Here's a JSFiddle fixing most of that up.](https://jsfiddle.net/6wb2xedc/4/)

```css
.price-table {
  display: table;
  width: 630px;
  height: 233px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 51px;
}
.price-table ul {
  display: table-row;
}
.price-table__content {
  display: table-row-group;
  border: 1px  #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}
.price-table__content ul {
  display: table-row;
}
.price-table__content ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 5px;
}
.price-table__content ul li:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  padding-left: 138px;
}
.price-table__content ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  text-align: left;
}
.price-table__content ul li:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 153px;
}
.price-table__content ul li:nth-child(4) {
  padding-left: 140px;
}
.price-table__content ul li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 142px;
  padding-top: 42px;
}
.price-table__content-third-row {
  display: table-footer-group;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}
.price-table__headers {
  display: table-header-group;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.price-table__headers ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 13px;
}
.price-table__headers ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 107px;
  border: none;
}
.price-table__headers ul li:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  background-color: #283645;
}
.price-table__headers ul li span {
  text-align: center;
}
.price-table__headers__column {
  display: table-column;
}
.price-table__headers__column-group {
  display: table-column-group;
}
```

```html
    <section class="price-block">
  <article class="price-table">
    <header class="price-table__headers">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li><div><span>База</span> <span class="price-table__item-value"><br>1,99 USD</span></div></li>
        <li><span>Стандарт</span> <span class="price-table__item-value"><br>3,99 USD</span></li>
        <li><span>Анлим</span> <span class="price-table__item-value"><br>9,99 USD</span></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="price-table__content">
      <ul class="price-table__content-fist-row">
        <li>Розовый фильтр</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="price-table__content-second-row">
        <li>Смайлики</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="price-table__content-third-row">
        <li>Комментарии</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Agree with the comments about a more minimal question though for next time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And yes of course I will be more attentive next time.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there span is an inline element thats why it's not taking margin etc. Issue seems here:

```
.price-table__headers ul li:nth-child(2) {
padding-left: 65px;
```

}

instead of this you can use something like:

```
.price-table__headers ul li:nth-child(2) {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjuravinder/6wb2xedc/6/)